# Bold numbers in a paragraph of words

Tags: php

is there a way that I can bold the integers in a string? Example I query this sentence "3 x 2 = 6" to display. I want to hold the 3, 2 and 6. So that when it is displayed, the 3, 2 and 6 are bold

Comment: yes, I'd do it via a preg_replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to replace numbers with numbers enclosed in `<b>` tags:

```
$str =  "3 x 2 = 6";
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $str);
```

prints

```
<b>3</b> x <b>2</b> = <b>6</b>
```